# Read Data From excel with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a vb.net console application and i am trying to read data from all excel files in a folder. In the second loop i get these error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.

Thanks for help.

Here is my code...

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim objFSO, objStartFolder, objFolder, colFiles, Path, a

    objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objStartFolder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Excel Files"
    objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
    colFiles = objFolder.Files

    For Each objFile In colFiles
        Path = objStartFolder + "\" + objFile.Name
        Dim objexcel, objWorkbook, ex
        objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objexcel.Application.Visible = True
        objWorkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.Open(Path)
        ex = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For i As Integer = 1 To 50
            a = ex.Cells(i, 5)
            MsgBox(a)
        Next
        objexcel.Quit()
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ex.Cells(i, 5)` doesn't return a string, rather an object representing the [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range(v=office.14).aspx) you've specified. So to access the value you need to change the type

```
MessageBox.Show(CType(ex.Cells(i, 5), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value.ToString())
```

You will need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in your project. You will then also be able to strongly type your Excel objects if you want, ie:

```
Dim objExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

Also on a side note you should probably stop using COM objects (`Scripting.FileSystemObject`) and use native managed .Net code instead. You can get the same functionality as above by just using the following code

```
        'Get me all filenames with file extension .xlsx
        Dim fileNames() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Excel Files\")

        'Loop through array of filenames
        For Each fileName As String In fileNames

            'Other excel code here

            objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        Next
```